# How could I manage Graylog to parse my JSON logs correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filebeat, graylog2, graylog

I have an rails app and I'm trying to configure logging to graylog. Pipeline consists of next steps:
1) Logs are written to file in JSON format by SemanticLogger gem. Log message consist of header info (first level tags) and payload with several levels of hierarchy:

```
{
  "tag": "mortgage",
  "app": "sneakers",
  "pid": 3448,
  "env": "production",
  "host": "thesaurus-mortgage",
  "thread": "91090300",
  "level": "info",
  "name": "Sneakers",
  "payload": {
    "class": "EgrnListenerWorker",
    "method": "work",
    "json": {
      "resource": "kontur",
      "action": "request_egrn_done",
      "system_code": "thesaurus",
      "id": 35883717,
      "project_id": "mortgage",
      "bank_id": "ab",
      "params": {
        "egrn": {
          "zip": "rosreestr/kontur/kontur_4288_2018-10-11_021848.zip",
          "pdf": "rosreestr/kontur/kontur_4288_2018-10-11_021848.pdf",
          "xml": "rosreestr/kontur/kontur_4288_2018-10-11_021848.xml"
        },
        "code": "SUCCESS"
      }
    },
    "valid_json": true
  },
  "created_at": "2018-10-11T17:44:58.262+00:00"
}
```

2) File is being read by Filebeat service and sent to Graylog.

And graylog could not parse correctly payload contents:

[image]

As you can see - keys are concatenated with ":" in one string in such manner: key1=value1:key2=value2. This is not what I am expected. It would be perfect if I could manage graylog to parse contents of payload into different fields with names payload.key1, payload.key2 and so on (so I could perform search on these fields)

ps: my log data is heterogeneous, i.e. payload contents depend on functionality it was produced by, so I expect that there would be a huge amount of different fields of a kind "payload.xxxxx" - is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a filebeat question since filebeat only ships the logs in their original JSON format (zipped, if wanted).

From the Graylog Website: http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/extractors.html

Using the JSON extractor
Since version 1.2, Graylog also supports extracting data from messages sent in JSON format.

> Using the JSON extractor is easy: once a Graylog input receives
>   messages in JSON format, you can create an extractor by going to
>   System -> Inputs and clicking on the Manage extractors button for that
>   input. Next, you need to load a message to extract data from, and
>   select the field containing the JSON document. The following page let
>   you add some extra information to tell Graylog how it should extract
>   the information.

This should get you going.

Comment: Nope, extractors do not work, I’ve tried them already and I think that reason is that json format of payload key is broken at the moment when extractor comes to place. So it could not extract data from it

Comment: Wouldn't it be the correct approach to ask the greylog devs to fix their broken connectors? :)

Comment: They need help to do it ) First, we need to find out broken unit of our chain - my json log file or filebeat or graylog itself? All votes are against latter for now